# Selecting Specific Fields in Entityform to Display

Tags: views, entities

Goal: Create a single entity form whereby the the fields that the user sees and can enter information into depends on the tab that they're on.

Approach: I am trying to create a views for each tab. I want to select the field that show up and then create a contextual filter so that the view appears on the correct tab.

Problem: I am unable to select Entityform fields. If I were to create a view for submissions, that would be easy. All of the fields in the entityform would be available for me to select and create a view for inputted data. But the Entityform Type fields are not available.

I've tried to embed the entityform into a content type an then create a view out of that (with a relationship to the content type). When I select "Rendered Entity" under Format>Show in the view set up form, it displays the entire Entity Form. When I select "fields" it does not give me the option to select specific fields that I created in my Entityform.